# Append Second Link to Read More

Tags: excerpt, read-more

I'm looking for a way to filter the "Read More" link so I can append a second link and text.

I know how to filter the text but not the entire output, eg:

---

Standard post excerpt before the more quicktag.... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ut auctor ligula. Vestibulum ac lectus quis nisl tempor fermentum. Maecenas urna erat, convallis eu.

[Read More](http://#my-post-permalink-as-usual) | [Add a Comment](http://#my-comment-link)

---

Thank you for any links / advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook into `excerpt_more` filter, for more information see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more) page, as examples of use [Twenty Ten](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-content/themes/twentyten/functions.php#L251)'s and Twenty Eleven's function files.